# Preserve Terminal profile settings after restarting/quiting it

Tags: macos, terminal, preferences, ventura, defaults

How can change the default terminal profile to Pro (plus font and window size settings) so that after closing/quiting the terminal and restarting it I'm presented with the Pro-profile not the standard "default"? (MacOs Ventura 13.3.1 (a))

What I'd tried:

1. set the Pro as default; restart (close/quit and reopen) the terminal -> the Pro is not displayed
2. deleting all the other profiles (the Pro remains selected and I'm not sure if Default label appears under it); restart the terminal -> the Pro is not displayed
3. set 'On startup open new window with profile' Pro; after restart -> the Pro is not displayed
4. all of the previous steps combined (set startup, set default, delete all the others); after restart -> the Pro is not displayed

I noticed a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232753/how-to-make-terminal-open-every-new-tab-in-the-homebew-profile) but all the recommendations from there are included in my above attempts without working.

Besides all of these, although I'm selecting the font and window size, after restart, the terminal displayed does NOT use my settings.

Comment: Terminal is…well…at best, “Ok.”  It’ll get the job done.  But if you’re looking for a rock solid Terminal Emulator with excellent features like automatic profile switching, tmux integration, and much more, look to [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/).